# prawn error reading generated pdf

Tags: file, pdf, prawn

Have had prawn successfully running and generating pdfs in an application for the last 4 years without any issue. Files are being generated and downloaded from the application onto local machine successfully but when trying to open file getting the following error:

"there was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired"

Any ideas how to resolve would be greatly appreciated - error is occurring on Windows 10 machine and latest adobe readers (don't have old installed anywhere now to test if this is a compatibility issue with the latest versions of this software). Research suggests it might be something to do with header generation in the document and improved security related to this but not clear.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Could you provide a sample PDF that show the error?

Comment: Thanks for the response, discovered that the sever was truncating the download so that while a PDF was downloaded onto the local machine it was an incomplete file.

A simple reboot of the server solved this, though no idea why the issues occurred in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment for solution found, not got to bottom of why server was causing error though